# QGIS 3 (2.99) without Grass

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation, windows, qgis-3

I wanted to play around with QGIS 3 release candidate (2.99) and after installing on Windows, it looks like there is no version of QGIS that doesn't include GRASS.  Is this correct?

Comment: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#qgis-windows-weekly use the advanced install but there are still dependencies that must be installed for the functionatily in qgis to work

Comment: I have installer QGIS 2.99 via OSGEO4W 64.bit and got icons for QGIS Nightly desktop with and without GRASS 7.2.2 .

Comment: Strange.  I am not seeing the "without Grass" icon.   I will try installing again. Maybe I missed something during the install.